# Access EditItemTemplate from CodeBehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have problem dealing with EditItemTemplate.

What I am trying to do is to update my `TextBox txt_name` but I can't get what the user ingresses And I get the old value instead at the code-behind.

Am I missing something?

## FRONT CODE

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView_account" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="True"
    OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView_account_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowEditing="GridView_account_RowEditing"
    OnRowUpdating="GridView_account_RowUpdating" OnRowCommand="GridView_account_RowCommand"
    OnRowDeleting="GridView_account_RowDeleting" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView_account_SelectedIndexChanged"
    DataKeyNames="UID" Height="110px" Width="497px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UID" SortExpression="UID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="label_accid" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Name (required)" SortExpression="NyA">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_name" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NyA") %>'/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_newname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="label_name" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NyA") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email Address (required)" SortExpression="eMail">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_email" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("eMail") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_newemail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="label_email" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("eMail") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Options" ShowHeader="False">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton_update" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update"
                    Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton_cancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel"
                    Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton_delete" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete"
                    Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton_addnew" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="AddNew"
                    Text="Add New"></asp:LinkButton>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton_edit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit"
                    Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Manage Role" ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="Selectbtn" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Select"
                    Text="Select"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

## CODE BEHIND

```
protected void GridView_account_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    user u = Business.GetUser(((Label)GridView_account.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("label_accid")).Text);
    //HERE'S MY PROBLEM!
    u.fullname = ((TextBox)GridView_account.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_name")).Text;
    //txt_name is returning the old value and not the one the user has input recently.

    Business.UpdateUser(u);
    GridView_account.EditIndex = -1;
    fillgridview();
}//
```

Comment: I't's been a long time since I've made my last page so things like PostBack are things I could miss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you checking if Page IsPostback when binding your grid?  You need to not rebind it in the Page_Load if it is a post back, or else you will lose the new values, because the Page Init, Page Load events happen before other events, such as a Grid Updating event.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'll check that and tell you. You maybe are right on this... =)

Answer (score 1):

May be you are binding you grid on every page_load event. If so, you need something like this:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
       GridView_account.DataSource = "data source";
       GridView_account.DataBind();
    }
 }
```

or instead of

```
 if(!Page.IsPostBack)
```

you can use

```
 if (GridView_account.EditIndex == -1)
```

this checks, if grid is in edit mode. If grid is not in edit mode, you can bind your grid with data source.